# React Native: Counter not showing correct updated state

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Im trying to put together a simple counter which changes the quantity of an item. Using Hooks to manage its state, i update the value on screen correctly. However, the value the state holds when i console log is always one less than the value on the screen.

For example:

If starting value is 1, after pressing the plus button, the value on screen changes to 2 but in console the state value is still 1.

**Setup of Hooks and functions controlling the count:**

```
//Set Quantity
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);

//Set Item price
const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = useState(itemOptions[0].price)

//Counter Control
 const [disableMinus, setDisableMinus] = useState(true);

const addQuantity = () => {
    if (quantity === 1) {
        setQuantity(quantity + 1);
        setDisableMinus(false);
        console.log(quantity)
    } else {
        if (quantity > 1){
            setQuantity(quantity + 1);
            setDisableMinus(false);
            console.log(quantity)
        }
    }
}
const minusQuantity = () => {
   if (quantity === 1){
       setDisableMinus(true);
   } else {
       if (quantity > 1) {
           setQuantity(quantity - 1);
           setDisableMinus(false);
           console.log(quantity)
       }
   }
} 

return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: "center", paddingVertical: 20}}>

    <TouchableOpacity disabled={disableMinus} onPress={() => minusQuantity()}>

        <AntDesign style={{color: '#37BD6B'}} name="minuscircle" size={30}/>

    </TouchableOpacity>

    <Text style={{paddingHorizontal: 10, fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 30}}>{quantity}</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addQuantity()}>

        <AntDesign style={{color: '#37BD6B'}} name="pluscircle" size={30}/>

    </TouchableOpacity>
```

)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting const [ quantity, setQuantity ] first?

Comment: Sorry that was already set, i forgot to add that into the snippet. I've updated the above.

Comment: Could you please include where you are logging to the console? What you are experiencing may be expected behavior since state updates in React are asynchronous. 
Your best bet for getting the up to date value might be from the variable itself right before state setting calls. Happy to provide an answer once  I know where you expect to see the updated value.

Comment: Kindly see here for more documentation on setState’s asynchronous nature:  https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-tips-async-and-setstate-cb539ad62135

Comment: @rexessilfie i've added the console log to where i placed them to check the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters from `useState` are async.

You could log it this way

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(quantity)
}, [quantity]
```

This means: when dependency `[quantity]` change, execute the `function` passed as first param

To avoid stale closure (happening when 2 fast clicks or rand randers), you should use setters and passing it a function instead of the "current" value:

```
setQuantity(prevQuantity => prevQuantity + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you might set things up:

```js
const addQuantity = () => {
  ...
      setQuantity(oldQuantity => {
        const newQuantity = oldQuantity + 1
        console.log(newQuantity) // console.log moved here. Also could be console.log("Incremented quantity to:", quantity)
        return newQantity
      });
  ...
}
```

This approach would allow you to log the new quantity value beore it is set. In this approach, you can perform a specific action (in this case console.log) on a case by case basis.

On the other hand, the `useEffect` approach in @Poptocrack's answer will track all changes to the `quantity` state. It has significantly less code and could be more desirable depending on your needs.

Hope you find one that fits your needs best from the two approaches.